# utf8 not converting string in PHP

Tags: php, string, utf-8

Hello i have german client and i am getting string with german alphabet which i am trying to display properly in output.I tried utf8_encode to convert string but not working for me.

Code:

```
    echo "Desc Short=>". utf8_encode($obj->Desc_Short) . "<br>\r\n";
    echo "Desc Long=>". utf8_encode($obj->Desc_Long) . "<br>\r\n";
```

Output:

```
Desc Short=>Ablagefach mittig in GepÃ¤ckraumtrennwand;ESACO_UG(122)
Desc Long=>Ablagefach mittig in GepÃ¤ckraumtrennwand inkl. verschiebbarem Haltenetz
```

Comment: Why do you use `utf8_encode` at all? You should have data in `utf-8` and you won't need to use anything. Where the data come from - database?

Comment: No not from database i am using SOAP client web service to get the response from system. And in Output even i used utf8 or not its not displaying data properly as u can see there are few strings which are are not showing properly like here GepÃ¤ckraumtrennwand

Comment: Huge difference with your code after edit. What's the value of `$obj->Desc_Short` before using `utf8_encode` ?

Comment: i am getting the same vaue even if i use utf8_encode or not. This values are coming for web service system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to simply use utf8_decode and use php header to set encoding (or set encoding in HTML document).

For the following code:

```
<?php

header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
$x = 'Ablagefach mittig in GepÃ¤ckraumtrennwand;ESACO_UG(122)';

echo utf8_decode($x);
```

Output for this is:

> Ablagefach mittig in Gepäckraumtrennwand;ESACO_UG(122)

Comment: i have question here it will work offcourse but what if i have many variable to echo so do i need to use utf8_decode for every vaiable to echo or just defining header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' ) will work ?

Comment: @user3844830 If those variables come from SOAP service, probably yes. However you could put them into array and do it in loop or maybe you should contact with SOAP service provider or read documentation if there are any other options.

Answer (score 1):

Your output indicates that the string is already utf-8 encoded.

Either you would have to use utf8_decode() to get the umlaut or - better - change any component in your application to properly handle utf-8. :)

Answer (score 0):

parse the string through utf8_decode function
TRY :

> utf8_decode($obj->Desc_Short) 
>   utf8_decode($obj->Desc_Long)